# Nginx reverse proxying to HTTPS upstream getting 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: docker, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have this configuration:

```
upstream frontend_upstream {
    # FrontEnd part based on `frontend` container with React app.
    server frontend:3000;
}

server {
    ...
    listen 80;
    server_name  stage.example.com;

    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
        # Web it's a name of Docker container with a frontend.
        proxy_pass https://frontend_upstream;

        ...
    }

    # Setup communication with API container.
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api:9002;
        rewrite "^/api/(.*)$" /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name stage.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://frontend_upstream;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to connect to my application via HTTP and HTTPs, but `SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream` raises.

What is wrong with this configuration?
There are a lot of similar issues, but none of them helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    location / {
      # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
      # Web it's a name of Docker container with a frontend.
      proxy_pass http://frontend_upstream;

    ...
}
```

try this.

Your upstream most likely works on http, not on https.

Comment: It works for HTTP, but I want to make it working on HTTPs too.

Comment: if you want your _frontend_upstream_ to work on _https_, you need to configure ssl on _frontend:3000_.
or 
add _return 301 https://$host$request_uri;_ to your *http* server context.

Comment: Do you mean to add `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to the server with `listen 80`?